# If $f$ is continuous with $ \int_0^{\infty}f(t)\,dt<\infty$ then which are correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty}f(t)\,dt<\infty$. Which of the following statements are true ?

(A) The sequence $\{f(n)\}$ is bounded.

(B) $f(n)\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

(C) The series $\displaystyle \sum f(n)$ is convergent.

I am unable to prove directly but I am thinking about the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. For this function all options are correct. Is it correct ? I think not , as I have no proof in general.

Please help by giving a proof or disprove the statements.

Comment: None are true. ${}{}$

Comment: Please cite a proper example

Comment: You need to show some effort. Think of 'tent' functions around the integers of height $n$ and base sufficiently small so the function is integrable.

Comment: To be a little bit more specific, you can make a function whose graph looks like infinitely many triangles of width $4^{-n}$ and height $2^n$, whose peaks are at the natural numbers.

Comment: Check out the driac delta function.  However, if f is continuous and differentiable over the reals, I think all 3 are true... might need need to think harder...

Comment: @DougM I think it is true if $f$ is decreasing but it is not true in general

Comment: One positive example is never enough to prove something. While one negative example is always enough to disprove something

Comment: @copper.hat but according to integral test for series convergence, (c) must be true. right?

Comment: @Unknownx: No. See my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a function $f$ which is the sum of triangles, $\Gamma_n$ , where $\Gamma_n$ has base centered at $n$, having vertices at $(n+1/n^3,0)$, $(n-1/n^3,0)$ and $(n,n)$ i.e. function takes value $f(n)=n$ and outside the triangle $f$ takes value $0$, then, this function satisfies all hypothesis, and shows that all options are false.

Comment: I am unable to understand your defining function. Can you define more explicitly ?

Comment: my function is sum of $\Gamma_n$'s , it looks like the one drawn in the second answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f_n$ that looks like a sequence of "spikes" that get taller and taller but become very narrow something like this. 
[image]

- If you are interested in forming $f$ explicitly then refer to the original answer given by BigbearZzz here..[Let $f:[0,\infty)→[0,\infty)$ be a continuous function s.t. $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx<\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849745/let-f0-infty%E2%86%920-infty-be-a-continuous-function-s-t-int-0-inftyf)