# Let $f:[0,\infty)→[0,\infty)$ be a continuous function s.t. $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $f:[0,\infty)→[0,\infty)$ be a continuous function s.t. $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx<\infty$. Which of the following are necessarily true?

- $(1)$ The sequence ${f(n)}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is bounded
- $(2)$ $f(n)→0$ as $n→\infty$
- $(3)$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ is convergent.
  I am trying to find a counterexample which proves that none of the options are correct but unable to find the exact one. Am I right to think of some function like $tan(πx/2)$?

Comment: What have you tried? (My one hint until you show attempts: note that 3 implies 2 and 2 implies 1, so the problem would be really easy if you could show that 1 is not necessarily true.)

Comment: @Ian....Edited for you.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 No, 3 is not true, it is obviously contradicted by the failure of 2 which you already noted. The integral test only holds under a monotonicity assumption.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 You forget that the integral test require the function to be monotonic.

Comment: @mathlover The example you suggested won't help you much here. Can you make up a continuous function with the following properties: $f(n)=n$, $f(x)=0$ if there is no $n$ such that $x \in [n-2^{-n},n+2^{-n}]$, and $0 \leq f(x) \leq f(n)$ if $x \in [n-2^{-n},n+2^{-n}]$? If so, then $f(n)$ won't be bounded but $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ will be easily seen to be finite.

Comment: Will $tan(πx/2)$ work? I hope it should, however it is piecewise continuous. Please confirm.

Comment: No, it won't. It's not continuous on all of $[0,\infty)$ anyway.

Comment: @Ian ...thanks for your $f(x)$ example which however seems to me difficult to contruct without having your visual approach. Kindly help me to visualize your $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Try to construct a function $f$ of the form $$f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$$ 
where $f_n$ is supported around $n$ (this means that $f_n(x)=0$ when $x$ is far from $n$) such that for $a_n=\int f_ndx$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n<\infty\ .
$$

For example, $f_n$ that looks like a tall triangle with very a narrow base, as suggested by other users. In this case $f$ would look like a sequence of "spikes" that get taller and taller but become very narrow.
[image]

Comment: @BigbearZzz..the point which is still confusing me is that as $n→\infty$, the area of  each triangle approach ($1/2$)($\epsilon$)(1/$\epsilon$)$=0.5$. Then why sum of areas is finite?

Comment: @mathlover I think it'd be a better idea to let the height of $f_n$ be $n$ with the base of $\frac 1{n2^n}$.

Comment: @mathlover There's no reason why the height should be the reciprocal of the width. The height could be huge while still being much smaller than the reciprocal of the width.

Comment: @Ian . I had Dirac delta function (a non- mathematical function) in my mind.

Comment: @BigbearZzz...the Dirac-delta function$\delta(x)$ (a non-mathematical) has unit area under it.Do you claim that a function (mathematical) exist with zero area under it?

Comment: a continuous function..?

Comment: @mathlover The only nonnegative continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ with a zero integral is the zero function. But that's not a problem: in your problem you don't need the spikes to have *zero* area. They only have to have an area which is so small that they sum up to something finite. To do that while making the height blow up, you need to make the width go to zero even faster than the height blows up. Making the width go to zero like the reciprocal of the height won't do, because as you've said you'll get something like an infinite sum of some nonzero constant.

Comment: @mathlover Excuse me, I don't follow your reasoning. When did I claim something like that (to be honest, I am not even sure of what did you think I was claiming)... Would you mind explaining that again?

Comment: @Ian...i understand your point of 'making width to zero even  faster than the height blows up' but doesn't that make the function discontinuous at those points? (similar to Dirac-delta function $\delta(t-a)$, which is discontinuous at $t=a)$)

Comment: @mathlover I've just uploaded the image of $f$. I hope that it should clear up your confusion. If there's anythin you still want to ask, please feel free.