# Let $f:[0,\infty) \to[0, \infty)$ be a continuous function such that $\int_0^{\infty} f(t) dt <\infty$ then find the correct option

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to[0, \infty)$ be a continuous function such that $$\int_0^{\infty} f(t) dt <\infty$$ 
then which of following  are true

(1) the sequence $\{f(n)\}$ is bounded

(2) $f(n) \to0$ as $n \to \infty$

(3) the series $\sum f(n)$ is convergent

i think option 1 and 2 is true, and option 3 is false.but not able to prove 1 and 2 and disprove 3.

any hint please

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849745/let-f0-infty→0-infty-be-a-continuous-function-s-t-int-0-inftyf?rq=1

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109776/which-of-the-statement-is-true-about-a-continuous-function-f0-infty-rightar?rq=1